# Line completion with custom commands

Tags: bash, unix, customization, autocomplete

my Python program can be launched with a range of different options (or subcommands) like:

```
$ myProgram doSomething
$ myProgram doSomethingElse
$ myProgram nowDoSomethingDifferent
```

I want it to use auto-completion with  so that if i type "myProgram d" it returns "myProgram doSomething" and if i type "myProgram n" it renders "myProgram nowDoSomethingDifferent". This is similar to the average use of the module *rlcompleter*, but it does not pick possible completion options from the filesystem (or from history) but from a custom set of strings (that correspond to the available options for my program)

Any idea on how to implement this?

I'm aware of the variable PYTHONSTARTUP (that should point to a file I don't know how to write).

As a working example, django-admin (from the django package) has the same exact feature i'm looking for

Comment: that is a bash question. You'd have to customize bash to make it work. It has nothing to do with python.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Create a file "myprog-completion.bash" and source it in your .bashrc file. Something like this to get you started...

```
_myProgram()
{
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  case "${cur}" in
    d*) use="doSomething" ;;
    n*) use="nowDoSomethingElse" ;;
  esac
  COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$use" -- $cur ) )
}
complete -o default -o nospace -F _myProgram  myProgram
```

Comment: Can this be used with aliases?  I have [gist](https://gist.github.com/vko-online/8fc32fb6bcf0369b3ab0) and i want autocomplete on some websites like twitter google etc, any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

There is the module **[optcomplete](http://furius.ca/optcomplete/)** which allows you to write the completion for bash autocompletion in your python program. This is very useful in combination with optparse. You only define your arguments once, add the following to your .bashrc

```
complete -F _optcomplete <program>
```

and all your options will be autocompleted.

Comment: optparse is not deprecated and replaced with argparse. Prefer argcomplete : https://github.com/kislyuk/argcomplete

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in other answers, in bash this can be done with the bash-builtin `complete`. Easier than writing a function (as in [richq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/427608/3596168)) is using `complete`'s option `-W` which lets you specify a list of words. In your example this would be:

```
complete -W "doSomething doSomethingElse nowDoSomethingDifferent" myProgram
```

As it is a one-liner you don't have to create a file for this, but you can just put it in your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly you want line completion on the command line before your python script starts. Then you shouldn't search for a python solution, but look at the shell features.

If you are using bash you can look at /etc/bash_completion, and at least on debian/ubuntu you should create a file in /etc/bash_completion.d/ that specifies the completions for your program.

Comment: +1. I would go for this one. If you have a finit set of completions it's super simple to set it up. And it gives the user an interface they're used to.

Answer (score 3):

As well as I know, PYTHONSTARTUP is for commands to be executed when the interpreter starts up [[1]](http://www.python.org/doc/1.5.2p2/tut/node4.html). `rlcompleter` is for autocompletion *inside* your script, if it is using `readline` library. Something like this:

```
$ ./myscript.py
My Script version 3.1415.
Enter your commands:
myscript> B<TAB>egin
myscript> E<TAB>nd
```

In your example you want to complete on the *shell* command line. This autocompletion is a shell feature (either `bash` or `zsh`, whatever you use). See, for example, [an introduction to bash autocompletion](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316) (also [part 2](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/317)). For `zsh` see, for example [this guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-satzsh.html#N102BF).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program to select an command line option even though you only used an abbreviated form of this option you should have a look at the [optparse module](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) in the standard library.