# How to set the following in .cshrc for aliasing

Tags: linux, shell, unix, csh

I have following alias in my .cshrc

```
alias fe-fat  "source fat  /prj/work"  
alias fe-fat1 "source fat1 /prj/work"
```

I wanted to know if we can set some variable for fat/fat1 and club the above 2 aliases into a single alias somewhat like the below, so that whenever I type `fe-<variable>` in the Unix terminal the above alias should work

```
alias fe-<variable> "source <variable> /prj/work"
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think that's possible with `alias`.

What are you actually trying to achieve?

It'd be simple enough to write a bash script that launches other commands based on a parameter (so you'd type `fe <variable>` instead of `fe-<variable>`).

It's not really worth it with only 2 commands but you could also provide a custom auto-complete script: See [Line completion with custom commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427472/line-completion-with-custom-commands)

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you wouldn't just alias it to something that takes a parameter?

```
alias fe "source \!:1 /prj/work"

fe fat   #=> source fat  /prj/work
fe fat1  #=> source fat1 /prj/work
```

Comment: Hi Bryan,Thanks for the solution it worked well                             Had one more query to the above solution                          for example i have word's quiet big say like "fat_abcd" etc,So typing this long word "fe fat_abcd"
So is there a way we can set an alias for "fat_abcd"   like "fab"
and then use ur above workaround "fe fab"                      I I tired aliasing but it didnt work so is there a way we can do that

Comment: @Jamesbond I don't believe so; the best idea may just be to give that its own alias like `alias feb "source fat_abcd /prj/work"`. If you want that kind of functionality I'd use something like zsh which offers [global aliases](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/53/ZSH-Gem-19-Global-aliases/).